# Response from Protected WebAPI is the HTML of the Sign in to my account Microsoft Page

Tags: asp.net, adal, webapi

**What I want**: My Web App, to call my Protected Web Api, which in Turn calls another Web Api on behalf of the originally Web app user.

**Issue** : My [Authorize]'d Web Api Methods are actually returning the HTML of the Sign in your Account page, versus the content of my page.

I was able to reproduce this by doing the following

Download the git example here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-admin-restricted-scopes-v2

1. Add a Web API Blank Controller.
2. Add the following Code

```
[Authorize]
  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<string> Test()
  {
      return "Test ok";
  }
```

3. *This works if I call it from a Web Browser directly and you get prompted to login properly but since what I want is an OnBehalfofFlow, I need a Client to call the Web Api, versus a browser.

I have a Web App client that is registered and configured to call a .NET CORE version of my Web API OnBehalfOfFlow and it works perfectly. However, I need to use some Asp.NET Framework stuff that doesn't work in core, so I am converting to .NET Framework.

So I take the GroupManager example above and configure it to use the same settings as my .NET CORE AD App Registration.

I then take my GroupManager and run it locally in the browser.
I then point my Client at that Uri, instead of my .NET CORE app

The calls are made, but instead of getting real responses, I merely get back a text represtentation of the HTML for the Microsoft Sign On Screen...

point the Client back to my .NET Core and it works perfectly. I am only changing the Uri here as the GroupManager sample and the .NET Core are the same otherwise.

Any thoughts on what is going on?

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Could you please analyze the access token you send to web API via https://jwt.ms to check if you have the right scope?

Comment: Hi and thanks! Jim. The Aud, Azp, Name, Preferred_username, Scp and Ver (as I am using 2.0 tokens and updated the Manifest to accept those from Null to 2), all look good. I am re-using an app registration that I know works when I point towards the .NET CORE app I have. So the same token creation, scopes etc

Comment: Using Application Insights on the Web API, I can see a 401 occurred as App Insights lists it as a failure. However, the response to the actual Web app, is a 200, with the content being the Sign In Page HTML.

Comment: @JimXu what I tried to do was add breakpoints in OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications methods such as OnAuthenticationFailed, but they ever get called. I also added a Public construct onto my Controller. I then added a VerifyUserHasAnyAcceptedScope extension and call it in the Constructor. I check for scp but its NULL even though scp is populated in the token before its sent. Verified with jwt.ms. Lastly, I guess I dont understand why a protected web api is passing back html of the sign in page period. It has no re-directs per configuration details in ms docs.yet the .NET Core app works

Comment: Is that the access token from the web app cannot call web API A?

Comment: Hi @JimXu correct. If I call any method that doesnt need [Authorize] it works fine, but soon as I try to [Authorize] I get that weird response. I consider it weird lol, because normally you'd get redirected to that page, but since its a protected Web Api, that does on behalf, it doesn't have a redirect. I have a full repro that is the sample from MS, plus a super minimum web app client, separate from my own real web app client.

Comment: @Nishant-MSFTIdentity yes I still do, my apologies on the super delay I was at the mayo clinic recovering and just getting back online. I could really really use your help.

Comment: @Nishant-MSFTIdentity if there was a working onbehalf flow that is NOT core that would be great. I really don't understand why its literally posting back the html of the sign in page versus actually just logging in.

Comment: @MMEG Hope you are doing well now! Please allow me some time to investigate this issue and I will post here as soon as I have something.